# Recommendations for security testing a Drupal site?

Tags: 7, security, testing

I'm about to relaunch my company's website using Drupal 7. I'm the sole web engineer in our IT department, so I have a lot on my plate as we approach the launch date. As this is my first major Drupal site, I want to be certain that it is as secure as possible. I have completed as many proactive security measures as possible, including following the [secure configuration](https://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration) and the [best security practices](https://drupal.org/developing/best-practices) guides on drupal.org, I've subscribed to the security newsgroup, and hardened the LAMP server using industry best practices.

Now that I have completed due diligence with regards to proactive security, I want to run a security audit before we go live to be able to generate a report stating we are "as secure as possible" for management. I usually do all of the testing by hand, page-by-page, using the [OWASP Web App testing cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet); however, I'm new to Drupal, this site is hundreds of pages, and I have limited time.

What are your recommendations for security testing a Drupal site of this size? I have access to Rapid7's Nexpose Enterprise, so I will be using that for some automated testing. I do not want to use hosted scanning tools, but will consider security-audited tools that I can install myself to use. Do you have security checklists you go by, similar to OWASP, but specific to Drupal 7? Any other advice for things I might have missed are also appreciated!

Comment: You'll always need to define specific tests to comply with your internal security standards, of course, but for general things there's the [Security Review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) module. The specific tests will obviously vary wildly depending on what modules and configurations you're using. Apart from the obvious xss/injection attacks what you're testing for will depend on what a module is supposed to do, and how it interacts with core and other modules in the system

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You can try to improve the [password strength](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_strength)
- To make all passwords stronger, the [Two Factor Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa) module is helpful
- The [Security Review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) module is a good call, as is the [Paranoia](https://drupal.org/project/paranoia) module

Comment: Excellent answer that could not come from a better source. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. It's a bit of a hard question to answer because the topic is so broad. If your review (I'm especially curious about Nexpose) does find anything then the last step is... https://drupal.org/security-team/report-issue :)

Comment: You're right, it was hard to ask as there are some many facets to security; however, the options given will be a great start. I will be sure to report anything Nexpose picks up, if it does at all.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this. Nexpose did not find anything related to Drupal, which is great news, although it should be noted that it is more of a network and server vulnerability scanner. I could add custom vulnerability checks, but Security Review is already doing that for Drupal, and it has been especially useful in the last few months. I also just purchased your book, which now I am getting more comfortable around Drupal, I am going to start reading and working through. Thanks for all you do!

Comment: I noticed that Secure Code Review module (recommended in @greggles linked article) is in development status, which creates a new risk in and of itself if run on a production website.

Comment: Secure Code review should not be installed on a production website. Paranoia and security review really need to be run on production, but the others could be run on a development copy of the site.

Comment: By the way, I added 2 more modules that should also be run on production: tfa and password_strength.